# Alarm sound always standard WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I try to call alarm with my custom sound, but the sound always standard. What i doing wrong? Sound file placed in a Solution root folder. Here is my code. Changes in xml manifest and references are correct and alarm shows right content at right time but the sound is standard...

```
Alarm alarm = ScheduledActionService.Find(alarmName) as Alarm;

if(alarm != null) {
   RemoveAgent(alarmName);
}

alarm = new Alarm(alarmName);
alarm.BeginTime = showTime;
alarm.RecurrenceType = RecurrenceInterval.None;
alarm.Content = message;

if(soundFile != "") {
   Debug.WriteLine("Alarm Sound set to " + soundFile);
   alarm.Sound = new Uri(soundFile,UriKind.Relative);
}
```